# Storing a temporary data outside of DbContext in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, data-structures, entity-framework

I have a performance issue with a few methods in my Service Layer. Methods that are causing me troubles have some logic, but it's db connection that takes over 95% exec time. The problem is unfortunately hardware, the machine is just slow. But, let me explain the software problem first:

The scenario goes like this (simplified):
Company sells cars, there's `Car` entity and `PurchaseOrder` entity. In the application, there is a `Car` view with all `PurchaseOrders`. There is a function to determine `PurchaseOrdersStatus`. It wouldn't be slow, but it must query the "slow" database a few times. Queries are very simple, like:

*"Check if `FooId` exists in `bar` table".*

If the car has a few purchase orders - the query is veeery fast. But when the car has hundreds of orders - it's getting very slow. Cause this query must be performed many many times. I came up with the solution:

1. Query all `FooId`s from `bar` table
2. Store this list of ids in the memory
3. In those hundreds of calls I'm checking if the id exists in the memory, which makes it way faster.

My question is, **is there a pattern of "prequering" data from database, putting it into memory?**

In my data persistence classes, like `CarData` I literally have "Initialization" method and member lists with ids. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

**EDIT:**

I'm doing one big query in the fast database, it's really fast even for a lot of records. To get "the status" I need to do a few more queries, that are in tables totally not connected to each other, some of which are in very slow db (btw. The db architecture is really terrible, but it's a legacy db, so all I can do is complain). It's possible to do the cross-database one query (built of subqueries, like `... WHERE carId IN (select cardId from ...` - but it's really slow.

**EDIT2: My proposed solution**

In my project I have a few `FooData` classes, some of them have corresponding `FooCache` class. Cache looks similar to Data, it has DataContext, Collections (cached list of ids or whatever I need) and one method `Initialize`. I inject `FooCache` into `FooData` via IoC (so every time `FooData` is created), **BUT** I don't initialize it. Only in methods where I need caching I call `FooCache.Initialize();` at the beginning. `FooData` before going to the database, checks if FooCache is initialized. If it isn't, it goes to the db.

Comment: Pretty sure EF does that already(`.Load()` + `.Local` property), doesn't it?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble figuring out your exact question. My interpretation was "is using an in-memory cache an acceptable way to avoid SELECT N+1s?", to which my answer is below.  Now you're saying you have to do "a few more" queries that are slow.  Is "a few more" relative to the number of `PurchaseOrders`?  If so, you still have SELECT N+1 problems.  If you want help optimizing the query, Database Administrators would be a good place to ask: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a pattern of "prequering" data from database, putting it into memory?

**Yes**, it's commonly called "caching" and it's used for this purpose.

> when the car has hundreds of orders ... this query must be performed many many times.

You are running into possibly the most common performance problem encountered by programmers using an Object-Relational Mapper like Entity Framework, called [SELECT N+1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-n1-select-query-issue).  In short: this is when the number of queries your application executes grows linearly relative to the number of records in your database (or some subset of it).

The best way to avoid SELECT N+1 problems is to produce better SQL, either by directly writing a view or stored procedure in the database, or by changing how you're using the ORM so it generates better SQL.

In Entity Framework, navigation properties make it difficult to fully appreciate when the code is hitting the database.  My personal preference is to **never use navigation properties in Entity Framework**.  They introduce loads of issues and this is one of them.  I want my ORM to be a way to *think* in SQL while *writing* in C#, but navigation properties seem specifically designed to hide away all that "scary" SQL and keep you thinking in C#, which makes it very hard to contain problems like SELECT N+1.  Instead of using navigation properties, compose your `IQueryable`  objects as needed in LINQ.

If you are committed to navigation properties, then your next best bet is to **use `Include` to eagerly load related entities** into properties you know you're about to traverse, as explained [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx).

What you are proposing is **in-memory caching**, which may or may not be a great solution depending on your constraints.  The main issues to consider with caching are:

1. Keeping the data fresh.  Make sure your cache is expiring more frequently than your data is changing, or you can end up using outdated data. If you're caching in preparation for one data processing cycle and then throwing the cache away, this is no problem.  If your data is unlikely to change during application runtime (e.g. unit conversion rules), you can get away with a long expiry.  If this is primary data that your users are continually editing, this is probably not the right solution.
2. Not querying more than you need.  It's generally very hard to restrict the query that populates the cache to only the data you need, without directly tying it into the primary query (and then why not solve the problem with LINQ?), especially if you're trying to re-use the cache.  If the amount of possible data you'll ever get at once is reasonably small compared to your memory, that is no problem, but *make sure you aren't just guessing about that*.

As long as you've considered the above points, using a cache is certainly better than tolerating SELECT N+1s.  As common as they are, I've never seen a situation where a SELECT N+1 couldn't be refactored into some constant number of queries relative to the number of records in the database.

Comment: I can't think of a way to not use navigation properties. I concede that it may be my inexperience that's the problem here, but how would you go about loading a Foo and all of its related Bars without nav props?

Comment: Oops, I wrote my "edit" in your answer. Can't see the option to remove it:/

Comment: Anyway, I know `SELECT N+1` is not a good solution. That's why I do 5 big queries, which are not that bed. And then operates in the memory.

Comment: @Flater `Foos.Join(Bars, foo => foo.BarId, bar => bar.Id, (foo, bar) => new FooBar { Foo = foo, Bar = bar })`.  Or its equivalent linq (`from foo in Foos ...`)

Comment: @CarlLeth thanks! I do use eagerly loading for my big query. Unfortunately my sub queries are in the different database, so I can't join them (even if I would try, it would be slow - cause I tested it in pure sql in SQL Server Manager). Anyway, I choose "in-memory caching". 1 and 2 - are not a problem. I'm caching, doing stuff, throwing away. I'm getting slightly more than I need, but the time grow is close to 0. I was looking for a sample code, that would show how to implement "pre-caching" in my `Data layer`. I rather not do this in the `Service Layer`

Comment: It sounds to me exactly like the kind of thing I'd expect a Service Layer to do, actually.  I wouldn't think a Data Layer would concern itself with querying the database.  It's a bit hard to talk about layers because they mean different things to different people, but it sounds to me like your solution is working well.

Comment: @CarlLeth I edited my question with my proposal explained. What do you think?

Comment: @IshThomas I think there's a lot to talk about that goes way beyond the scope of a single question (this question particularly), and probably beyond the scope of this exchange.  A great place for independent review of code like that is Code Review here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @CarlLeth you're right. I'm gonna write a better question on codereview. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

let me untangle all the foos and bars. You are calling sql in a loop:

```
foreach(var purchaseOrder in CarPurchaseOrders)
{
    //check if a payment exists
    //select * from payments where id=@id"
}
```

the Answer is "DO NOT QUERY SQL IN A LOOP"

instead:

```
select * 
from 
    purchaseOrder po
left join
    payments p
on 
    p.purchaseOrderId = po.id
```

brings back all the purchase orders, with the payment if they have been paid. in a single query.

If for some reason you cant join the tables. (perhaps they are in different databases) you can do:

```
select * from payments where id in ('a','b','c'.....)
```

Comment: Can you clarify `you can do`? I did try one huge query, which sub-queries  but it's very slow - even running from SQL Server Manager. Look at my edit

Comment: ..where in (select... can be problematic, it sounds like you are missing indexes? but I cant be clearer when you are talking about foo and bar! run the query analyser on your big query.

Comment: No indexes are missing, literally same database, but on the faster machine works good. So I have to fix a hardware slowness with the software hack. Is it really bad to cache temp data? I'm doing as you suggested `select * from payments where id in ('a','b','c'.....)` although `('a','b','c'.....)` I'm getting from cache (which I had to pre-query at the beginning)

Comment: I posted an edit with my current solution. I followed your answer *DO NOT QUERY SQL IN A LOOP*. With the solution I purposed number of queries is always the same. No matter how many records are in the db. Unfortunately I couldn't use one query, case data is in two dbs